# Can I hide http endpoints or https endpoints from the client depending on which protocol they want to use

Tags: .net, wcf, exception, wcf-client, wcf-configuration

I've followed various instructions from here to configure my WCF service to support both http and https.  Basically, they've all pretty much pointed out that I need to duplicate my endpoints for each protocol, so my server is configured like this:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="MyApp.WebServices.ServiceBehavior" name="MyApp.WebServices.ServiceLibrary">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpsBinding" name="AuthenticationService" contract="MyApp.WebServices.IAuthenticationService" />

    <!-- HTTP enpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicBinding" name="AuthenticationService" contract="MyApp.WebServices.IAuthenticationService" />
</service>
```

So I've got different bindings, one for http, and one for https for each endpoint.

My issue is when I create a client for this webservice using Visual Studio 2010 Service References.  I'd like to be able to just point the service reference to either:

```
http://mysite.com/myapp/servicelibrary.svc
```

or

```
https://mysite.com/myapp/servicelibrary.svc
```

My ideal scenario is if the service reference is using http or https, only the appropriate endpoints using the same protocol are pulled into the client app.config file.  As it is, if I reference the http servicelibrary, I get both pairs of endpoints like this:

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="https://ip-0af84f03/myapp/ServiceLibrary.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="AuthenticationService"
        contract="Services.IAuthenticationService" name="AuthenticationService" />
    <endpoint address="http://mysite.com/myapp/ServiceLibrary.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="AuthenticationService1"
            contract="Services.IAuthenticationService" name="AuthenticationService1" />
</client>
```

So, when I try to access a function from AuthenticationService, I get this error:

> An endpoint configuration section for contract 'Services.IAuthenticationService' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found.  Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.

I know I can get rid of the error by manually removing the unwanted duplicate endpoints from my app.config on my client, but my preference would be for them not to show up in the first place when setting up the service reference.

Is this possible?